# Creating one view for taxonomy page teasers so I don't have a ton of views

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

this seems like a simple problem but I can't seem to find a straight forward answer for Drupal 7.  I have a ton of taxonomy vocabulary pages and I just want to configure them the same all the way through the site. So I just want one view that formats them all.
Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have the taxonomy and views module enabled you should see a couple of disabled views and one of them is a view that format the taxonomies pages and their XML feed. Enable them and you will be able to play with them as need it.

See image below:

[image: Taxonomy Views]